# Как можно контроллеры хранить не в папке Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2

В класcическом расположении файлов и папок в ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0, файлы распределяются в папки в зависимости от слоя.

- Контроллеры в папке Controllers
- Вьюшки в папке Views
- ViewModel, Model тоже в своих папках, и так далее.

Мне такая система расположения файлов не нравится, потому что много приходится в момент разработки перемещаться вообще в разные области проекта. Я хочу организовать компонентную структуру разбиения.

То есть, есть например компонент сообщения форума. И всё что касается этого компонента хранится в его папке.

Далее компоненты могут входить друг в друга, например компонент форум, в него входит компонент сообщение форума. Соответственно это будет организовано папками и подпапками.

Вопрос: как такую структуру организовать на ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC, если в документации сказано что все контроллеры должны обязательно лежать в папке Controllers, как можно изменить это поведение?

Можно ли контроллеры в папке Controllers хранить в подпапках этой папки?

**Добавлено**

Так как у меня клиентский код написан на `vue.js` отдельным проектом, то мне не нужно что бы Razor Views тоже работали из папки компонента, конечно этот вопрос теоретически тоже интересен, но мне в этом надобности нет, так как у меня Razor Views вообще нет (кроме одной главной на всё приложение).

Comment: А вы не пробовали посмотреть на разбиение/структурирование приложения на отдельные Area?

Comment: @AK ну так, можно, конечно, попробовать, но это не то что я хочу, не настолько гибко. Мне что бы папки в подпапках могли бы быть. Оптимальный вариант это переопределить дефолтовую логику работы определения места контроллеров. Возможно даже  в подпапках папки Controllers, но лучше что бы и её можно было переименовать.

Comment: @AK Вот нашёл подобный вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372926/asp-net-mvc-core-custom-controller-factory