# Как ASP.Core работает с пользовательскими контроллерами?

Tags: c#, архитектура, asp.net-core

В каком месте посмотреть исходный код ASP .NET Core , в котором происходит вызов пользовательских контроллеров, какой класс за это отвечает?

Comment: Там же где и в asp.net - в фабрике контроллеров. https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level4/4_7.php

Comment: Да это то что я искал спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создание отдельных экземпляров контроллеров происходит в фабрике контроллеров.

Вы можете создать собственную фабрику контроллеров, реализовав интрейфейс IControllerFactory:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    public object CreateController(ControllerContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReleaseController(ControllerContext context, object controller)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Собственно, там всего два метода - один отвечает за создание контроллера по входным параметрам запроса (точнее - по контексту), второй - за действия по завершению контроллера.

Более подробно тема раскрывается в [учебнике по ASP.NET на сайте professorweb](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level4/4_7.php) - отличия .net от .net core в создании контроллеров не особо велики, но если что можно посматривать в декомпилированный студией код, либо в [исходники на гитхабе](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers ?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/DefaultControllerFactory.cs

Comment: А нельзя эти знания использовать для моего вопроса - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798145 ?