# Создание asp.net mvc проекта с onion архитектурой и использованием ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Изучаю mvc 5 на metanit. Добрался до пункта архитектура приложений. И тут возникло много вопросов. Изучаю конкретно onion архитектуру и принцип UnitOfWork. И в связи с этими пунктами у меня появился вопрос:

В примере на metanit есть вот такой вот конструктор контроллера:

```
IBookRepository repo;
IOrder order;
public HomeController(IBookRepository r, IOrder o)
{
    repo = r;
    order = o;
}
```

И если запустить этот код без ninject, тогда вылетит ошибка, что для контроллера отсутствует базовый конструктор без параметров. И первый вопрос получается в том, как ninject делает так что такой конструктор уже не требуется? Как работает контейнер зависимостей Ninject?

Comment: Технически, создание экземпляров класса может делаться не только через `new`, есть ещё вариант через рефлексию (гуглить класс Activator.CreateInstance), подробнее можно почитать начиная [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715920/213987). Все DI работают на том или ином способе (рефлексия - очень медленная штука, поэтому очень важно как-то сократить это время) неявного создания объектов и анализе его конструкторов. Вторая часть вашего вопроса (неявная) это то, как DI работает совместно с [фабрикой контроллеров и активаторами действий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803434/213987).

Comment: @AK получается ninject сам создаёт базовый конструктор и это остаётся вне поле моего зрения, и он уже не нужен поэтому такой вариант работает только с использованием ninject?