# Можно ли сделать контроллер синглтоном (Singletone)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть "легаси" проект на ASP.NET MVC 4
Как я выяснил в отладчике все контроллеры (а также и репозитории) не являются синглтонами, а создаются каждый раз при каждом web-запросе.
Хотелось бы сделать часть контроллеров синглтонами.
Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579123/how-to-make-the-controller-a-single-instance-per-application-in-asp-net-mvc) есть пример, но он для ASP.NET Core, не для обычного ASP.NET MVC.
Подозреваю, что нужно инициализировать эти контроллеры в Global.asax, но не могу найти - как?

Comment: Нет, тот пример вам не подойдёт: в core ввели полноценный DI движок и вам [остаётся](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/6.5.php) буквально одну строчку менять, чтобы движок клепал синглтоны. И если вы ищете такую же одну строчку для обычного .net mvc то её там нет - и нужно сначала подтащить весь движок DI либо налабать свой велосипед из палок и веток. А в классическом нужно написать свою реализацию фабрики контроллеров https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803490/213987 И ещё. Ну реализовать-то можно, но ЗАЧЕМ? Легаси - вот и пусть живёт как легаси.

Comment: а в чем смысл делать контроллеры синглтонами?

Comment: почему не использовать `singleton` или `жизненный цикл "singleton"` в контроллере? объекты контроллера новые будут создаваться, а ресурсы будут общими

Comment: (в чем смысл делать контроллеры синглтонами) ну, например, хранить в полях класса что-то, что не нужно хранить в базе. Или кешировать ответ (а не лезть каждый раз в БД)